# How to use Devel::Cover with prove?

Tags: perl

I see there are some similar questions here and on http://www.perlmonks.org but I still do not get it.
Imagine I have a project with a 'lib/' and a 't' directories. I run my tests with 'prove':

```
$ cd $PROJECT_ROOT
$ prove ./*.t
```

I want to get a report in html for one or more files in the 'lib/' directory. I do not want reports for the files in the 't' directory.
A simple example should be enough. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `perl Makefile.PL` or `perl Build.PL`
2. [`cover -test`](http://p3rl.org/cover)

Comment: It is not a distributable project. there is just a directory "lib" full of *.pm and a "t" No makefiles.

Comment: @Berov, I had the same issue and Daxim's suggestion is correct. You can still add a skeleton Makefile.PL or Build.PL to your project and then get your coverage report.  If it helps, I did contact the author of Devel::Cover and he confirmed that this is the way to go about it.

Comment: Amazingly this worked just fine. 
I created a bare-bones Makefile.PL, ran cover -test, and now I have an exhaustive set of HTML pages in folder cover_db.
WHo would guess it will be so simple.... 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to note that I found some time ago that when using Module::Build it is as easy as ```./Build testcover```. Still not sure how to get report for only a set of files in lib/ say lib/Foo/Bar/*.pm.

Answer (score 7):

The proper way is to always start out with Makefile.PL/Build.PL, just as selected answer suggests. However, sometimes you are not the one who started out, so...

I used to make a fake makefile:

```
 % cat Makefile
 test:
      prove -Ilib -r t
```

The following also seems to work (w/o touching ANY files on disk):

```
cover -t -make 'prove -Ilib -r t; exit $?'
```

This only works because of how perl's `system`/`exec` handle an argument with shell metacharacters in it (`;` in this case) and may break in the future if `cover` decides to quote it more rigirously. Also it shouldn't work under windows. I wish `cover` had a `-prove` option instead.

This one still generates coverage for *.t as well as CPAN modules at nonstandard locations. This behaviour can be fixed using +select/+ignore options (see the [Devel::Cover's manpage](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Cover#SELECTING-FILES-TO-COVER)):

```
cover -t +select ^lib +ignore ^
```

So the tl;dr "magic" command is

```
cover -t +select ^lib +ignore ^ -make 'prove -Ilib -r t; exit $?'
```

*EDIT* The following didn't work for me - it only prints short summary:

```
 PERL5OPT="$PERL5OPT -MDevel::Cover" prove -Ilib -r t
 cover -t +select ^lib +ignore ^
```

Note that `prove -MSomething` applies `Something` to `prove` itself and doesn't pass it on (unlike with -I).

Comment: I recommend using

-make 'prove -v -Ilib; return $?;'

... rather than "echo", otherwise test failures don't cause a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Actually make 'prove -v -Ilib; exit $?;'  otherwise it fails under bash - you can only `return' from a function or sourced script. It works in most other shells.

Comment: @ChrisLamb Updated according to your comments.

Comment: ^ may be special in some shells (e.g. zsh with extendedglob turned on). In this situation one has to quote it: cover -t +select '^lib' +ignore '^' ...

Answer (score 1):

Make `prove` run every test file with Devel::Cover activated:

```
$ prove --exec 'perl -MDevel::Cover=-silent,1 -Ilib' t/*.t
```

By default this will print the statistics after each test file. That’s why I added `-silent => 1`.

To print the complete statistics at the end add:

```
$ cover -summary
```